# how to perform rotate transformation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to perform **rotate transformation** using javascript
when I use this code

```
document.getElementById("sc").style.transform='rotate(8deg)';
```

it works properly, but when use **8deg** in variable then it not respond
like

```
let gg=8;
 document.getElementById("sc").style.transform='rotate(${gg}deg)';
```

so how can i perform **rotate transformation using veriable** in javascript

Comment: One way is simply using as `'rotate('+gg+'deg)'`

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) use backticks `\``, not single quotes `'`

Comment: Thank you  sir ji.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template strings:

```
let gg=8;
document.getElementById("sc").style.transform=`rotate(${gg}deg)`;
```

or you can just concat the variable instead:

```
let gg=8;
document.getElementById("sc").style.transform='rotate(' + gg + 'deg)';
```